# How to get user input with string

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

My project is very similar to the famous ATM problem. I have to create a hotel check in/check out system. I have to get the user input for the last name and confirm it. However when I try to return the string, it tells me it cant convert string to int.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Keyboard {
   private Scanner input;
   String lastName;

   public Keyboard() {
       input = new Scanner( System.in);
   }

   public int getInput() {
       lastName = input.nextLine();
       return lastName;
   }

}
```

Comment: The return type on your method is an int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: @MFisherKDX The name should be a `String`, no need to convert to `int`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In this case, since your issue is so simple, it's OK.  But for next time, please read how to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your example here isn't complete since there is no main to call the getInput() method.  Just something to keep in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int getInput() {
   lastName = input.nextLine();
   return lastName;
}
```

Here you said, that getInput will return **int**, change it into

```
public String getInput() {
   lastName = input.nextLine();
   return lastName;
}
```

For more information, take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: @heymiki  if you consider this answer sufficient, mark the question as answered, please.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you declare `getInput` method will return an `int` by:

```
public int getInput()
```

Since the name should be a `String`, not an `int`, you need to adjust your method signature:

```
public String getInput() {   
    lastName = input.nextLine();    
    return lastName;    
}
```